# Add list items from text file

Tags: list, development

I want to create items in my List, where text file string equal item's Title. It must be very easy but.

```
 protected void ProcessingList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server:port/myWeb/");
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

                stringItem = reader.ReadLine();

                SPList oList = web.Lists["_departmentList"];
                SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();
                oSPListItem["Title"] = stringItem;
                oSPListItem.Update();
            }
        reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Error list here (it's really huge, sorry):

```
> [SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException: An unhandled exception in the Execute method of the object-insulated shell code in a partially trusted application domain: An unexpected error.] `//it was translated error message`

> Server stack trace: 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAppDomain.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxyForShim.ExecuteInternal(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) 

> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.ExecuteDelegate.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String currentAffinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) 

> Exception rethrown at [1]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9() 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart userCodeWebPart)

>[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
  at SharePointListItems.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1.ProcessingList(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: So have you tried running this code? What happens? Errors? (BTW, is `stringItem` declared?)

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Large error list. `stringItem` declared before as `public string stringItem = "";`

Comment: Well you're going to have to share the errors for us to be able to help you.

Comment: First post updated

Comment: Edited (error listing as code), it's easier to read.

Comment: I never thought that it's so difficult...
Maybe it would be better to use any different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but `if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)` always return false value.